# What is the best practice to change the default font from a masterpage in a MySite webb application?

Tags: css, cssregistration

I have a mysite web application. In this webapplication there is the my site host site collection. In this site collection I have my custom masterpage with my custom css file registration. This css file is located in the style library. This custom masterpage is already deployed by a wsp.

I was creating a custom css and registered it in the masterpage with the tool sharepoint designer. On the mysite host site the css was OK. But When you click on some link like (My Content, My Site) I dont see the styling in my custom css. In the source code from the browser I dont see the css registration.

I did some research and see that each my site has its own site collection, masterpage definition, css definition.

What is the best practice to change the default font?